# Notes on a video in JW player

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer

I am trying to use JW player on my website but I have encountered some issues. Can somebody just help me to point in the right direction, I would be really grateful.

Issues-
How to take notes on a video so that if I play that same video again, I'll be shown those notes(not on the video itself but on a separate div beside that video) along with the timestamp?

Reference- I want this functionality like that of pluralsight video player.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, please see the example here:
http://se.jwplayer.com/~amcneil/POCs/annotations/